# How to set Permanent Kernel runtime parameters?

Tags: kernel, configuration

I am currently using Ubuntu 20.04 machine.

I want to change the value of a kernel runtime parameter permanently in my system.

In which file I can add the **token = <new_value>** , so that this will override the default kernel parameter values?

Also I can see a number of configuration files inside the `/etc/sysctl.d` directory, in which order these files are read by the system?

Comment: In some file in `/etc/sysctl.d`. The files are read in lexicographic (alphanumeric) order, so you can add a new file or use an existing file there keeping in mind the sorting.